# Strange problem with the fluid library in openmodelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I wrote a simple code to experiment the use of the PrescribedPump machine in the Fluid package of the standard library. I'm using OpenModelica 1.13.2.
I would like to pump some water from a tank to another one, by using a prescribedPump driven with a constant value of 10000.

Here the code:

```
model PompaPilotata

  package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.ConstantPropertyLiquidWater;

  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system ;
  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank bacinella1(redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    T_ambient = system.T_ambient, T_start = system.T_ambient, crossArea = 4, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial,
    height = 10, level_start = 2, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial, nPorts = 1, p_ambient = system.p_ambient,
    use_HeatTransfer = false, use_T_start = true, use_portsData = false)  ;

  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank bacinella2(redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    T_ambient = system.T_ambient, T_start = system.T_ambient, crossArea = 4, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial,
    height = 10, level_start = 2, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial, nPorts = 1, p_ambient = system.p_ambient,
    use_HeatTransfer = false, use_T_start = true, use_portsData = false)  ;

  Modelica.Fluid.Machines.PrescribedPump Pompa(redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    medium(h(stateSelect = StateSelect.default), p(stateSelect = StateSelect.default)),N_nominal = 100, V = 0.1, allowFlowReversal = false,
    checkValve = true, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, m_flow_start = 0.0000001,
    massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, nParallel = 1, use_HeatTransfer = false, use_N_in = true) ;

  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant Costante(k = 10000);

  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe tubo1(redeclare package Medium = Medium,allowFlowReversal = true,
    diameter = 0.1, height_ab = 0, isCircular = true, length = 5, nParallel = 1) ;

  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe tubo2(redeclare package Medium = Medium,allowFlowReversal = true,
    diameter = 0.1, height_ab = 0, isCircular = true, length = 5, nParallel = 1);

equation
  connect(tubo2.port_b, bacinella2.ports[1]);
  connect(Pompa.port_b, tubo2.port_a);
  connect(tubo1.port_b, Pompa.port_a);
  connect(bacinella1.ports[1], tubo1.port_a);
  connect(Costante.y, Pompa.N_in);
end PompaPilotata;
```

I get this error message from the compiler:

In file included from C:/OpenModelica1.13.264bit/include/omc/c/util/modelica_string.h:38:0,
                 from C:/OpenModelica1.13.264bit/include/omc/c/openmodelica_func.h:52,
                 from PompaPilotata_model.h:6,
                 from PompaPilotata_06inz.c:2:
PompaPilotata_06inz.c: In function 'PompaPilotata_eqFunction_237':
C:/OpenModelica1.13.264bit/include/omc/c/meta/meta_modelica_data.h:231:21: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'omc_Modelica_Fluid_Machines_PrescribedPump$Pompa_flowCharacteristic'
 #define mmc_mk_real mmc_mk_rcon
                     ^
C:/OpenModelica1.13.264bit/include/omc/c/meta/meta_modelica_data.h:225:45: note: in definition of macro 'mmc_unbox_real'
 #define mmc_unbox_real(X) mmc_prim_get_real(X)
                                             ^
PompaPilotata_06inz.c:3005:139: note: in expansion of macro 'mmc_mk_real'
   data->simulationInfo->realParameter[7] = mmc_unbox_real(omc_Modelica_Fluid_Machines_PrescribedPump$Pompa_flowCharacteristic(threadData, mmc_mk_real(data->simulationInfo->realParameter[5])));
                                                                                                                                           ^
In file included from PompaPilotata_model.h:23:0,
                 from PompaPilotata_06inz.c:2:
PompaPilotata_functions.h:223:15: note: expected 'modelica_real {aka double}' but argument is of type 'void *'
 modelica_real omc_Modelica_Fluid_Machines_PrescribedPump$Pompa_flowCharacteristic(threadData_t *threadData, modelica_real _V_flow);
               ^
: recipe for target 'PompaPilotata_06inz.o' failed
\tools\msys\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make:*  [PompaPilotata_06inz.o] Error 1
\tools\msys\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make: * Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Compilation process failed. Exited with code 2.

Someone can explain me what does it mean and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Note that the model works fine with OpenModelica's -d=newInst (from the nightly builds). But you probably wanted to redeclare the function as in Markus' answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model does not work in Dymola eiter, but it gives the following hint:

```
Function Pompa.flowCharacteristic_Unique7 is neither external nor has an algorithm. It should have been redeclared.
```

Therefore redeclaring the function for the flowCharacteristic should help. Copying this part from `Modelica.Fluid.Examples.PumpingSystem` and reducing the values for `V_flow_nominal` by a factor of 1000 (which is a wild guess) gives:

```
  Modelica.Fluid.Machines.PrescribedPump Pompa(redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    redeclare function flowCharacteristic = Modelica.Fluid.Machines.BaseClasses.PumpCharacteristics.quadraticFlow (V_flow_nominal={0.001,0.0025,0.005}, head_nominal={100,60,0}),
    medium(h(stateSelect = StateSelect.default), p(stateSelect = StateSelect.default)),N_nominal = 100, V = 0.1, allowFlowReversal = false,
    checkValve = true, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, m_flow_start = 0.0000001,
    massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, nParallel = 1, use_HeatTransfer = false, use_N_in = true);
```

With the second line actually being added.